# How do you precompile the native extensions for a ruby gem for linux?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, precompiled

We have a ruby application that depends on a gem with native extensions (in this specific case Nokogiri). However, for various reasons we cannot install the build prerequisites (such as build-essential, libxslt-dev, ruby-dev, etc) for that gem onto our production host.

**Is there a (standard?) way to repackage the gem with the native extensions pre-built?**

It should be possible (it seems to be fairly standard to do this for Windows), but I can't find any documentation on the subject.

Note that we only need to support a single platform, with known versions of all system libraries (Ubuntu 9.04 Server 64 bit, Ruby 1.8.7).

UPDATE:
We're using Bundler, so we want to still have a **gem** to install at the end of the day, **not a debian package**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this for gems that use [rake-compiler](http://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler) for building their C extensions (which is most of them).

You need to do the following on a machine that is identical to the one you want to deploy to, or it simply won't work:

Install the build prerequisites for building C extensions:

```
# apt-get install build-essentials ruby-dev # ... etc
# gem install rake-compiler
```

Unpack the gem you want to rebuild:

```
$ gem unpack nokogiri
```

Build your shiny new precompiled gem:

```
$ rake native gem
```

You can now install the native gem on a machine without any build tools installed:

```
$ gem install pkg/nokogiri-1.4.3.1-x86-linux.gem 
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.4.3.1-x86-linux
1 gem installed
```

Comment: I'll just share that I had more success checking out the sparklemotion/nokogiri repository from github, changing to the versioned git tag for the version I needed, and ran `rake native gem` there. Putting gems packaged this way in your vendor/cache folder with Bundler works a treat!

Comment: @Jacob can you please elaborate on this ? "changing to the versioned git tag for the version I needed"

Answer (score -1):

**Build machine**

To have the correctly platformed version for all of your gems already cached,
package all gems in `vendor/cache` on an identical machine:

```
$ bundle package --all
```

---

**Prduction machine**

Install all gem dependecies already cached that requires to have the correctly
platformed version using the gem cache:

```
$ bundle install --local --deployment
```

Comment: This does not pre-compile native gems.